# Json_encode/decode in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, serialization

I have an array on view `$all_set` which contain some ids.now i want to pass this array in controller using form submit.for that i used the j son encode and decode.

on my view:

```
<?php $all_set=json_encode($all_set); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="all_set" value="<?php echo serialize($all_set); ?>">
```

the above value contains(as i saw in page source):

```
<input type="hidden" name="all_set" value="s:26:"{"0":"1","5":"2","13":"3"}";">
```

Now on controller:

```
$result=$this->input->post('all_set');

           $result= unserialize($result);
           $result=json_decode($result);
           print_r($result); die;
```

This gives me error and i am not getting any array on controller.
Error:

```
Message: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 5 bytes
```

Why is this so? please Help.

Comment: Why are you serializing a JSON text?

Comment: actully i am first time using json for sending the data to view to contoller but the webnetmobile.com gives me answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `htmlspecialchars()` to your serialize.

```
<input type="hidden" name="all_set" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(serialize($all_set)); ?>">
```

**EDIT**

Why this solves the problem? Let's see the OP's quoted output first:

```
value="s:26:"{"0":"1","5":"2","13":"3"}";">
      ^     ^
```

I added `^` to mark the problem source - your value included quotation marks, which made browser see this input more less like this:

```
value="s:26:" {"0" "1" , "5" : "2","13":"3"}";">
```

It simply closed the string once it found matching `"`. There're are special characters in HTML, including `<`, `>`, `&`, `"` which have to be converted to entities if they are expected to be passed literaly. So by calling `htmlspecialchars()` we convert all these characters and the markup would look like this:

```
value="s:26:&quot;{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;5&quot;.....
```

Browser interprets it now correctly, displays correctly and sends back correctly but to not treat it as part of markup.

**EDIT 2**

In fact unserialize is quite uselss in your code. Get rid of `serialize()`/`unserialize()` completetly - your json encoded data is just pure string, so you need only `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: can u plz tell me why we have to add the htmlspecialchars()??

Comment: Please check R S's answer instead. Using unserialize() leaves you open to a security vulnerability.

Comment: awesome..gr8 explanation..gr8 help..+1 for explanation

Comment: @JonathanAmend R.S. gives the same level of security as using serialize. No data tha comes from user can be trusted. If you build a form and put **your** data to hidden fields and then user submits that form back, then there is no more **your data** there. It **user data**. It is **ALL** user data. And you have to verify it again - it **absolutely** makes no difference you put it there in at first. That's the rule of thumb in **any** client/server code. And the question was about the problem with using serialized data in form, not about how to pretend to  understand the security issues.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com You are only leading someone off a cliff if you let them continue to use unserialize() on data that is received from the user. base64_decode() does not have the risk of arbitrary code execution while unserialize() does. You might as well be letting him eval() it.

Comment: I'm not in to the back and forth... but if you look at (1) a major framework like say magento this is how the send most of the ajax request back to the server using base_64 (2) take a look at your data size for every quote your adding 5 more characters. what if your sending really large file?  czoyNjoieyIwIjoiMSIsIjUiOiIyIiwiMTMiOiIzIn0= vs s:32:&quot;s:26:&quot;{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;5&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;13&quot;:&quot;3&quot;}&quot;;

Comment: In fact serialize/unserialize is unnecessary in OP's code, which I just spotted. And for educational purposes, the correct answer should involve `htmlspecialchars()` due to the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="hidden" name="all_set" value="<?php echo base64_encode($all_set); ?>">

$result= base64_decode($result);
$result=json_decode($result);
```

Comment: while this will work too, it's not a fully correct solution, because you are **working issue around**, instead of removing the real culprit.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com This is not true. R S is correct in removing the use of unserialize(). If you are unserializing data that is supplied from the user's end, you are leaving yourself open to a pretty huge security vulnerability, because the data passed back to your script can be manipulated to cause your server to execute any PHP code that the attacker wishes: http://heine.familiedeelstra.com/security/unserialize

Comment: No data from user can be trusted. That's why you always do server side verification. If you consider base64 to be any form of protection against this then you miss the point.